# How to handle duplicate records when importing data from RDMS to hadoop using sqoop?

Tags: hive, sqoop

Suppose if we use incremental import in sqoop for importing data from RDMS to Hadoop and some data that we already imported in hadoop earlier got updated in RDMS and when we are again importing using sqoop incremental import we also get that recently updated data which was already present in our Hadoop which leads to data duplicates, so how can we avoid data duplicates when importing data using sqoop in such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is written once read many (WORM) approach and the incremental load need a planned strategy. There are following guideline you can follow and validate your current requirement

1. If the table is a small (few thousand records) and not having too many columns, better to refresh the entire table. This will work faster and safer.
2. In case, the table is too big and incremental load has add/update/delete operations, you can think of staging the delta and perform a (left outer) join to re-create data new set and insert overwrite. Make sure you keep a history location for validation.
3. There is 3rd approach which can also be followed for better performance. For large table and large delta, you can create a version number while sqooping & fetch date for each delta & park it into a delta directory. Merge all the full load and delta load and apply rank function to see the latest record on top. This can also be achieved via view.